# How to refresh a webpage once azure sql database table is updated

Tags: asp.net, ajax, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I'm working on a webPage app using C# ASP.NET, it retrieves me data from Azure Sql Database once I click my submit button.

```
protected void BtnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                string connStr = "Server=*******";
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
                conn.Open();

                string strQuery = "select **** from myTable";
                SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, conn);
                Label1.Text = sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                conn.close();
        }
```

Now I'm trying to get my wabPage label.text updated automatically with the latest uploaded records in Azure Sql Database table, without using clock control, how do I achieve that?

Comment: You have to look for options like long polling or web sockets. Signalr may help you in this scenario.

Comment: Check my answer below. Also you don't need to worry about transfer protocols  as Signalr by default uses websocket with HTML5 browser if nto it lower down to Server sent event, Forever frame then  long polling.

Comment: Glad to know it helped for you.